# When should you not use GitHub GraphQL API?

Tags: github, graphql, github-graphql

Much has been written about the benefits of the GitHub GraphQL API. And this is a really great technology. The only thing I can't figure out is in what situations is it still better to use the good old REST API v3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github GraphQL API is subject to the following caveats:

- GraphQL API can only be accessed using authentication. You need a token to use this API. Thus, you can't use GraphQL in an environment where you can't secure the provisioning of this token. For example, in a web app without github authentication. This is a big caveat, especially for people who want to create web app or scripts that target only public repository informations.
- Searching [commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913948/search-commits-by-message-with-github-graphql-api) and [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382069/search-for-code-in-github-using-graphql-v4-api) using [the search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search) is not possible in Github Graphql. Only searching repos, issues and users are supported (for the search API)
- some features like [comparing commits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits) and getting [contributors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309272/github-graphql-query-for-project-contributors) are not possible yet in Graphql. Another example: you can't [recursively get a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669560/github-graphql-to-recursively-list-all-files-in-the-directory) using GraphQL API
- some mutations already available in v3 may not yet have been implemented in GraphQL (create commit, create tag, create branch etc...), checkout [mutations documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations)

Comment: @SergeyIsaev you're welcome, you can accept the answer if it's ok

Comment: [Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61277904/1705829) is possible in GraphQL with the `recursive` flag in `tree`